# Jenkins still running on localhost:8080 despite uninstalling it

Tags: windows, jenkins

Jenkins still running on localhost:8080.

Tried to uninstall it, removed jenkins files from program files etc..  But still running, very confused, searched drive etc for jenkins references, but none found, a bit puzzled tbh.

Add/Remove programs
Delete files in 'Program Files'
Jenkins still running in browser localhost:8080

Comment: You need to uninstall the Jenkins service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services#uninstall-using-powershell

Comment: That's the strange thing here, can't even see Jenkins running as service in Windows.

get-service (excerpt of output)
Stopped  IpxlatCfgSvc       IP Translation Configuration Service                                                        Running  jhi_service        Intel(R) Dynamic Application Loader...                                                      Running  KeyIso             CNG Key Isolation